# Javascript stopping a form from being submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to stop a form from being submitted if Javascript is turned off? I know you can do the hide show stuff. But is it possible to make sure that the form is unable to submit if Javascript is turned off? Since all people have to do is hit f12 and see whatever they want. I know people will tell me server side validation but I was curious if anyone does any special things with Javascript or Jquery besides the show and hide.

Comment: Nope. Server-side secondary validation is the way to protect against this.

Comment: You cannot do _special things_ with JavaScript (and by extension jQuery) when JavaScript is turned off, that would defeat the purpose of the option in the first place. Of course, you _technically_ could if there is a bug in the browser that will still let you execute JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make sure that the form is unable to submit if
>   JavaScript is turned off?

Yes.

What you need to do is build your form by default without a submit mechanism so that those without JavaScript can't submit the form while those with JavaScript enabled would be allowed to as you would use JavaScript to modify the form and make it submittable.

For example, make sure your form contains no inputs or buttons of type submit, and no buttons without a type attribute (the default type attribute for `<button>` is submit). You'd also need to have a form with more than a single text input as most browsers will submit a basic form with a press of the enter key. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/jprd4p5o/) vs [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sewec25L/).

Then using JavaScript you can modify the document in a variety of ways to enable the form's submission. For example, adding (or changing the type of) an input or button so that it was of type submit. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3pa4373r/)

Note however that this won't prevent anyone from using the browser's console from modifying your code and submitting the form, or possibly attempting a cross-site script submission from a server they control.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove event on submit button!

Write css class 'noscript' to form container and write styles to remove events from button submit
If js on - your form will work as normal
If js off - your button has no events as you want

Unfortunately if you press 'enter' on input form will be submitted

```js
//default when js turned on remove class 'noscript'
//document.querySelectorAll('.noscript')[0].className = '';
//also need to remove onsubmit attribute

//for test case not remove class 'noscript' 
//js turned off
```

```css
.noscript button{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="noscript">
  <form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input value='smth'>
    <button>
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: In case when js off we can hide all form inputs and form won't be submitted by enter